# Is there a way to "translate" types in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, types

Depending on the type of a variable I would like to call a templated function (which is given). The problem is, the expected types for the template won't fit directly.

**Example**:
If the type of my variable is `int`, then I would like to call the function `foo<classA>()`. If the type is `double` I would like to call
`foo<classB>()` and so on...

Until now I have called the function inside a switch case.

**My Question is**:
Is there a way to "translate" types? Sth. like a function to which I pass `int` and I will get `classA` back?
This way I could simply call the function like this: `foo<translate_type(variable)> foo()`

What I tried is, as I wrote, a switch case. Another possibility might be a templated function around the template. One which is accepting e.g. `int` and is then calling the right function `foo<classA>()`. Furthermore I would like to avoid Macros.

Maybe there is a better way in modern C++? One that is a bit better maintainable without using cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My Question is: Is there a way to "translate" types?

Of course. C++ has had this since forever.

```
template <typename T>
struct my_translator;

template<>
struct my_translator<int> {
    using type = classA;
}
```

And now you can write:

```
typename my_translator<int>::type
```

and get `classA`. This works with C++98 even, I think. It's basically how all of those type traits in the standard library are implemented, like [`std::make_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned).

If you use C++11 or later, you can make a shortcut beyond the above trait:

```
template <typename T>
using my_translator_t = typename my_translator<T>::type;
```

and then, you only need to use `my_translator_t<int>` to get `classA`.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Right you are. Changed that to C++11.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class T>
struct type_trait{using type=T;}; // can leave the type part out, and even the body, for errors/diagnostics
template<class T>
using type_trait_t=typename type_trait<T>::type;

template<>
struct type_trait<int>{using type=Foo;};
template<>
struct type_trait<double>{using type=Bar;};

template<class T> void func(){}

func<type_trait_t<int>>(); // calls func<Foo>
func<type_trait_t<double>>(); // calls func<Bar>
func<type_trait_t<char>>(); // calls func<char>
```

I think this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, you offered OP more than they bargained form, in the form of the clever default idempotent "translation". So +1. I think he accepted my answer because I focused on the "my question is" part.

Comment: @einpoklum I accepted your's because you have added some explanations that let me understand the code :)